# Image from URL not loading

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui

I'm trying to make a screen witch gets an image url from firebase real-time database and then load the image from this url. The problem is whenever i call the function withc gets the url from the database the image is not loading and the global variable withc hold the url has always the default value

**My function:**

```
@State var imageURL: String = "none"


func getCurrentUserProfilePictureURL() {
    
    let ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
    let userRef = ref.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "noid")

    // Get Current Profie Picture URL from Real-Time Database
    userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
        
        self.imageURL = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "photoUrl").value as! String
        
                    
    } withCancel: { error in
        print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
                    
}
```

**My Image View:**

```
    VStack {
        
        if let imageURLString = imageURLString, let url = URL(string: imageURLString) {
            AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                image
            } placeholder: {
                placeholder
            }

        } else {
            placeholder
        }
        
    }.onAppear {
        getCurrentUserProfilePictureURL()
    }
```

**My placeholder:**

```
var placeholder : some View {
    Image("user_icon")
        .frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment: .center)
}
```

**AsyncImage.swift:**

```
//
//  AsyncImage.swift
//  iGrow Goals
//
//  Created by George Sepetadelis on 27/8/21.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Combine

struct AsyncImage<Placeholder: View>: View {
    @StateObject private var loader: ImageLoader
    private let placeholder: Placeholder
    private let image: (UIImage) -> Image
    
    init(
        url: URL,
        @ViewBuilder placeholder: () -> Placeholder,
        @ViewBuilder image: @escaping (UIImage) -> Image = Image.init(uiImage:)
    ) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder()
        self.image = image
        _loader = StateObject(wrappedValue: ImageLoader(url: url, cache: Environment(\.imageCache).wrappedValue))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        content
            .onAppear(perform: loader.load)
    }
    
    private var content: some View {
        Group {
            if loader.image != nil {
                image(loader.image!)
            } else {
                placeholder
            }
        }
    }
}

protocol ImageCache {
    subscript(_ url: URL) -> UIImage? { get set }
}

struct TemporaryImageCache: ImageCache {
    private let cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()
    
    subscript(_ key: URL) -> UIImage? {
        get { cache.object(forKey: key as NSURL) }
        set { newValue == nil ? cache.removeObject(forKey: key as NSURL) : cache.setObject(newValue!, forKey: key as NSURL) }
    }
}

class ImageLoader: ObservableObject {
    @Published var image: UIImage?
    
    private(set) var isLoading = false
    
    private let url: URL
    private var cache: ImageCache?
    private var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    
    private static let imageProcessingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "image-processing")
    
    init(url: URL, cache: ImageCache? = nil) {
        self.url = url
        self.cache = cache
    }
    
    deinit {
        cancel()
    }
    
    func load() {
        guard !isLoading else { return }

        if let image = cache?[url] {
            self.image = image
            return
        }
        
        cancellable = URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
            .map { UIImage(data: $0.data) }
            .replaceError(with: nil)
            .handleEvents(receiveSubscription: { [weak self] _ in self?.onStart() },
                          receiveOutput: { [weak self] in self?.cache($0) },
                          receiveCompletion: { [weak self] _ in self?.onFinish() },
                          receiveCancel: { [weak self] in self?.onFinish() })
            .subscribe(on: Self.imageProcessingQueue)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink { [weak self] in self?.image = $0 }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        cancellable?.cancel()
    }
    
    private func onStart() {
        isLoading = true
    }
    
    private func onFinish() {
        isLoading = false
    }
    
    private func cache(_ image: UIImage?) {
        image.map { cache?[url] = $0 }
    }
}

struct ImageCacheKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: ImageCache = TemporaryImageCache()
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var imageCache: ImageCache {
        get { self[ImageCacheKey.self] }
        set { self[ImageCacheKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

Comment: There isn't really enough information here to help debug this. If you put a `print` before you set `self.imageURL`, does it print anything? If not, what error does it print in your `withCancel` closure?

Comment: @George this variable has always the default value ("none")

Comment: You need to show where you call getCurrentUserProfilePictureURL. Since it is asynchronous, you will need a way to not send the URL to the AsyncImage until you have a valid URL.

Comment: @jnpdx i'm calling it inside the `init` function

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things should change:

1. You need to only load your `AsyncImage` once you have a valid URL -- right now, you're trying to load right from the beginning, where the value is just "none"
2. You should not call `getCurrentUserProfilePictureURL` in `init`, since `init` on a SwiftUI `View` may get called *many* times and should not be used for heavy-lifting or code that shouldn't be run more than once. Instead, use `onAppear`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var imageURLString: String? = nil
    
    var placeholder : some View {
        Image("user_icon")
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120, alignment: .center)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let imageURLString = imageURLString, let url = URL(string: imageURLString) {
                AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                    image
                } placeholder: {
                    placeholder
                }

            } else {
                placeholder
            }
        }.onAppear {
            getCurrentUserProfilePictureURL()
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentUserProfilePictureURL() {
        
        let ref: DatabaseReference = Database.database().reference()
        let userRef = ref.child("users").child(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? "noid")

        // Get Current Profie Picture URL from Real-Time Database
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
            self.imageURL = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "photoUrl").value as! String
        } withCancel: { error in
            print("ERROR: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, `imageURLString` is an Optional -- if it doesn't have a value, the placeholder image is shown. Once it *does* have a value (ie when the asynchronous `getCurrentUserProfilePictureURL` finishes), it can start to load the `AsyncImage`

---

Based on the comments, you're using some sort of custom `AsyncImage` implementation. So, your code for that section may need to look more like (guessing, because I don't know what the implementation looks like -- this is based on your original code):

```
AsyncImage(url: url,
           placeholder: { placeholder },
           image: { Image(uiImage: $0).resizable() })
```

Comment: Thanks man, i'm gettings 2 errors:

1. on this line `AsyncImage(url: url) { image` the error:  `Contextual closure type '() -> Placeholder' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body`

2. on this line `placeholder: {` : the error: `Extra argument 'placeholder' in call`

Comment: I believe that you have probably made a mistake in implementing the code -- what I've provided compiles just fine with Xcode 13.0b4. Can you double check that it matches *exactly*?

Comment: `            VStack {
                
                if let imageURLString = imageURLString, let url = URL(string: imageURLString) {
                    AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                        image
                    } placeholder: {
                        placeholder
                    }

                } else {
                    placeholder
                }
                
            }.onAppear {
                getCurrentUserProfilePictureURL()
            } `

Comment: Edit your question with an update -- code doesn't appear correctly in comments. Also, it's unclear if you've copied my `var placeholder ...` code -- that could be causing your issue.

Comment: Also, please confirm what version of Xcode you're using. Although the implementation details may vary from beta to beta, the concept will be exactly the same of needing to wait for the asynchronous Firebase call to return before using the URL.

Comment: i updated my code, also i'm running this version: Version 12.5.1 (12E507)

Comment: `AsyncImage` shouldn't be available at all until iOS 13.0 (ie Xcode 13). Where are you importing `AsyncImage` from? It must be a 3rd party implementation. I'd need to know the details to write the correct code for it. But, like I said, the concept doesn't change at all -- the main idea is just making sure you wait for the URL.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a *guess* based on your original code, since I don't know what AsyncImage solution you're using.

Comment: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
I'm getting this on the AsyncImage line. And also i have another file called async image, i updated my question

Comment: I don't have any force-unwrapped optionals in my code. The error must be coming from your `AyncImage` code. I provided my answer assuming you were using the SwiftUI version. I don't currently have time to debug your `AysncImage` implementation as well. I will delete it if you want so you can get another answer, but I stand by the fact that the *concept* of waiting for the URL is what you need to implement. The `AsyncImage` code itself is a secondary issue.

Comment: Don't delete your answer, is useful :-)